# Calculation involving $\infty \in \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T(z) = {iMz \over 2iM - z}$ on the extended plane.

Does it then follow that

$$
T(\infty) = {iM\infty \over 2iM - \infty} = {iM \infty \over -\infty} = -iM \text{?}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Divide top and bottom by $z$ and get 
$$\frac{iM}{(2iM/z)-1},$$
and now since as $z \to \infty$ $2iM/z \to 0$ you get what your calculation was, namely $-iM.$

Answer (score 0):

Why not try $T(\infty)=\large\frac{iM\infty}{2iM-\infty}=\frac{iM\infty(-2iM-\infty)}{(2iM-\infty)(-2iM-\infty)}=\frac{iM\infty(-2iM-\infty)}{4M+\infty^2}$

$\large=\frac{iM\infty(-2iM-\infty)}{\infty^2}=\frac{-iM(2iM+\infty)}{\infty}=\frac{-iM\infty}{\infty}=-iM$,

I think this way avoids ambiguity, since I believe $2iM$ and $\infty$ would be linearly independant?